how to fill that holes in blender 3d modeling
I need the easiest method to fill these holes. I tried using Ctrl+F, but when I export the model for 3D printing, the slicer doesn’t recognize the edit.


If you don't care that it has a flat surface, in Object Mode you could add cylinders and boolean join them inside the holes.

You might want to use the 3d Print Toolbox add-on to check the manifold of the object.

Using Ctrl+F won’t work because it only adds a flat internal face, but your object has thickness. Instead, you need to use a disk-shaped object with thickness to match the inner wall of the cylinder to properly cover the hole. Since your object has bad topology, the most feasible solution I see is to either remodel it or use the following approach: Add a disk-shaped object with some thickness to fit and cover the hole. Although you can add more topology on top to make the cover more convex and polished, and ready for sculpting and smoothing, for simplicity, I’ll use this flat disk:

Hide the disk object, then add a Boolean modifier to the main object and select Union with the disk object as the target:

Go ahead and Apply the modifier. To check if your object is still manifold, go into Edit Mode and select Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold. Ensure that no vertices get selected to confirm that the object is still manifold and the operation was successful.

Also, check the 3D Print Toolbox addon for additional and more specific manifold checks.
